# mysql timestamp in between query

Tags: mysql

In the below i have a table1,table2 ,i am stuck with a query.I want find the timestamps in table2 which are in between two consecutive timestamps of table1 .How to form this query.

table1:

```
   id    timestamp
    1    2012-08-15 01:11:11
    1    2012-08-15 01:11:14
    1    2012-08-15 01:11:16 
    2    2012-08-15 01:22:11
    2    2012-08-15 01:32:11
    2    2012-08-15 01:33:11
    2    2012-08-15 01:36:11
```

table 2:

```
   id    timestamp
    1    2012-08-15 01:11:12
    1    2012-08-15 01:11:15
    1    2012-08-15 01:11:16 
    2    2012-08-15 01:23:55
    2    2012-08-15 01:26:11
    2    2012-08-15 01:34:11
    2    2012-08-15 01:36:01
```

Desired output:Get all rows of table2 which are in between the timestamps of table1 and if possible output timestamp of table1 also

Comment: What is the desired ouptput for the sample data you posted?

Comment: Where is the query that you are stuck on?

Comment: The query that i am stuck on is to get the logic of comparing the two rows from table1

Comment: What do you mean by *between*?  Is the interval open, closed, or open at only one end?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by *consecutive timestamps*?  If `table1` contains three timestamps `a < b < c` then any time between `a` and `c` falls between "two consecutive timestamps": either in `[a, b]` or else in `[b, c]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join `table1` to itself and then group to find consecutive timestamps, then join the result to `table2` as desired:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table2 JOIN (
  SELECT   a.timestamp start, MIN(b.timestamp) finish
  FROM     table1 a JOIN table1 b ON a.timestamp < b.timestamp
  GROUP BY a.timestamp
) t ON table2.timestamp BETWEEN t.start AND t.finish
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4dad7/1/0).

Comment: That is a very clever solution.

Comment: @eggyal:Hi i need one small change in the query .The timestamp to be compared with the same ids(for ex:all timestamps pertaining to id 1,then id2.....). How to get it